# python-pptx Change Hyperlink Color

Tags: colors, hyperlink, python-pptx

Is there a way to change the color of a hyperlink using python-pptx?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't change the color of the text:

```
p = Shape_TextFrame.add_paragraph()
run = p.add_run()
run.text = "Google"
hlink = run.hyperlink
hlink.address = 'http://www.google.com'
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,255,255)
```

I'd like to change the color from the usual blue to white, as my slide background is black and the hyperlink is getting blown out.

Many thanks for any pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the colour palette within the PPTX that is referenced as a template (as in https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/change-hyperlink-color-in-powerpoint--cms-30026).

I haven't yet found a way to achieve this via python-pptx.

Comment: That wouldn't be a solution if you wanted a specific link to change, rather than all of them. Which is why I didn't suggest editing the template. More interesting would be to take a standard template and alter its colours. (I should consider that for md2pptx.)